# VBA Help - Need to return a text from a specific cell to a OptionButton

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I need help to return a text from a specific cell and if the text matches with the configuration of the optionbutton, this option button will be set as true.

I tried to use this code bellow:

```
Dim texto1 As String
texto1 = "Testando Texto"
If Range("D3").Value = texto1 Then
    OptionButton1.Value = True
End If
```

Comment: You need to be specific about the type of Option Button you are using. Form Control/ActiveX Control? Also mention what error you are getting from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

For Option Button (form control on a sheet):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.Value = True
```

For Option Button (ActiveX control on a sheet):

```
ActiveSheet.OptionButton1.Value = True
```

For Option Button (on a form):

```
Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
```

FYI: you can use `Me.OptionButton1.Caption = your string` if that what you wanted in your question's title.